# How to make an HTTPS call on App Engine

Tags: java, google-app-engine, ssl

My app queries other web services via SSL. I've used Apache HttpClient to create https POST calls on my server to other web services. When I deployed my app to App Engine I got the following error:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax.net.ssl.KeyManagerFactory is a restricted class. 
Please see the Google App Engine developer's guide for more details.
```

My question is, how can I make HTTPS calls on Google App engine?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apache HttpClient is not supported [out-of-the-box](http://groups.google.com/group/google-appengine-java/web/will-it-play-in-app-engine) by App Engine. You will have to write a custom ConnectionManager that wraps [UrlFetch](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/index.html?com/google/appengine/api/urlfetch/package-summary.html). [This post](http://esxx.blogspot.com/2009/06/using-apaches-httpclient-on-google-app.html) explains it pretty well and provides you with sample code. I used that code successfully on App Engine before.

Answer (score 1):

You can just use a URL class to make HTTPS connections on the [app-engine](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/urlfetch/overview.html#Secure_Connections_and_HTTPS).

Something like this --

```
URL url = new URL(yourHttpsURL);
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));
StringBuilder responseBody = new StringBuilder();
String line;

while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
    responseBody.append(line);

reader.close();
```

The app engine also supports host validation using the FetchOptions class in the low-level API.